# Выбрать из строки подстроку, которая содержит число

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как  выбрать  из  переменной, которая содержит строку подстроку, которая содержит только числа.
К примеру имеем переменную вида 
`SET @i='name 112233 name'`
как правильно построить запрос, что-бы получить только числа в порядке их расположения в строке? 
Пробовал `SELECT @i = SUBSTRING(@i, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@i), LEN(@i));` но получаю ошибку  FUNCTION test.PATINDEX does not exist (test - имя БД). Так же пробовал через RLIKE, но на выводе получаю 1(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Шаг 1: объявить свою функцию */
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS digits_from_string;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION digits_from_string( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(32)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);

  IF str IS NULL
  THEN 
    RETURN "";
  END IF;

  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str );
  REPEAT
    BEGIN
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 );
      IF c BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c);
      END IF;
      SET i = i + 1;
    END;
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT;
  RETURN ret;
END |
DELIMITER ;

/* Шаг 2: использовать эту функцию */
SELECT digits_from_string('name 112233 name'); -- вернет '112233'
```

это функцию ты в последующем можешь использовать и в выборках из таблиц

Comment: отлично, спасибо большое, работает! 
Т.е. , как я понял, встроенных функций чтобы сделать это не существует?

Comment: Есть только встроенная функция [`REGEXP`](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Regexp.html), она проверяет подходил ли строка или нет под заданное регулярное выражение, считается что ее вполне хватает для обычных выборок из таблиц. Для более продвинутой работы с регулярными выражениями есть [такое расширение](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp)